# Should Kamailio and Asterisk be on different servers

Tags: asterisk, kamailio

Are there many disadvantages/advantages to having Kamailio and Asterisk on the same Server

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

For small deployments with low number of subscribers and active calls it makes sense to save resources and run both Kamailio and Asterisk on the same server.

Otherwise, running them on separate servers is the common out there, allowing to dimension each server based on processing needs. Usually, Kamailio needs fewer resources because it handles the signalling channel only. Asterisk may have to do heavy audio processing such as transcoding, audio conferencing or complex IVR menus, so it needs more powerful systems, sometimes with dedicated hardware.